# iTunes Connect: do I need to complete 'iOS Paid App' contract before I try to submit my app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, app-store

It seems like they want my bank info, tax info, etc in the 'iOS Paid App' contract... must 
I do all this before myapp has even been approved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can submit Free apps and have them approved and distributed in the App store without a Paid Apps contract submitted or in place.

If you submit a Paid app, and it as approved, it's availability in the App store will be postponed until after your Paid Apps contract is in place.  So if you don't want this delay, you should complete the Paid Apps contract well before your are ready to sell your apps.

Comment: Is it impossible to create in-app purchase products without this contract in place?

Comment: hi, a message appeared in mi itunes account of accepting the contract ( something like that) and i request de paid application contract but my app is Free, how can i deleit it? help :C

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I believe if it's free you can skip the bank info, but paid definitely needs that.

Comment: I can confirm you don't need to enter the bank info for a free app. But you still need to pay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you do. You cannot submit an app without a provioning profile and only paid developers get those.

Comment: He didn't ask about provisioning profiles, or about whether has to pay for the developer program. I'm rather mystified as to why you're getting upvotes for not answering the question.